# How to get data from etherscan.io?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get information from etherscan using php. I'm trying to get the "Value in ETH" and "Value in USD" but It doesn't work. **I would like to accomplish this with PHP** and **I know they have an API** but **I would still like to use PHP.**

[image]

It either returns an empty array, an array with a couple of members (but the members are "") or NULL.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$contentx = file_get_contents("https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0x4650769d2fF7e42deD1dEF920C5eCCd4185a9672");
   preg_match('#<span class="h5 mb-0" id="HoldingsETH">([0-9\.]*?)</span>#Uis', $contentx, $TokenETH);
   preg_match('#<span class="h5 mr-1 mb-0" id="HoldingsUSD">\$([0-9\.]*?)</span>', $contentx, $TokenUSD);

echo "<br>";
var_dump($TokenETH);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($TokenUSD);
```

If you have any suggestions on how to fix this, let me know.

Comment: Don't scrape, use [their API](https://etherscan.io/apis).

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
Out of pure curiosity, why are you scraping over using the API? and why restricted to PHP?

Comment: I've tried using the API cause it was my last resort but it doesn't work. I've actually found the answer to my question in the meantime, and I will publish my answer in a few days when I can except my own answer.

Comment: @LeonKunštek Can you please let me know what doesn't work in api ? i am looking for similar solution

Comment: @Akashsenta It would appear that I'm still using the same solution I posted in the answers below (bacause it was for a personal side project). If you want a different solution, I'd advise you to check out other API providers for Ethereum, like Ethplorer and Blockchain (if I recall correctly). I'm not sure if Etherscan's API became more user friendly, so I'd leave that to you and your fair judgement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in this youtube video `https://youtu.be/l2ajhoGCpuo`.
In the video the guy shows how to only get a certain part of the content from an external page. And if you use `explode()`, `str_replace()`, `strip_tags()` and `trim()` you can get any data you want from any external page.